# How to use gzip if it has not been enabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

This is a problem that I'm sure many people have come across when using shared hosting:

You want to turn gzip on but can't because it isn't enabled somewhere higher on the server.

The host is http://easily.co.uk but they do not support the use of .htaccess so don't offer any help (such as turning on gzip in server config.)

However, they do allow use of .htaccess but thats all.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are no way to gzip your content if the gzip mod is not enabled and if you can't use htaccess files as far as I know...

You can have a look to the [gzdeflate PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php), if you want, but you will be able to compress only your php files. The other files (js, css, images) will be uncompressed.

Comment: ok thanks. I can use .htaccess but gzip is not enabled higher on the server so when I try to use it in .htaccess it gives a 500 error.